# Dagger Hilt not injecting on tests

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to run a test using Dagger Hilt with Robolectric:

```kotlin
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@UninstallModules(LevelModule::class, AppModule::class)
@Config(sdk = [16, 28], application = HiltTestApplication::class)
@LooperMode(LooperMode.Mode.PAUSED)
@HiltAndroidTest
class LevelFragmentTest {

    @get:Rule
    var rule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Test
    fun testShowGameOverWhenTapAMine() {
        launchActivity<GameActivity>().onActivity { activity ->
            ShadowLooper.runUiThreadTasks()
            ...
        }
    }
```

The test fails on `GameActivity.onCreate` because all fields of GameActivity with @Inject are null.

GameActivity is:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

The modules are:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
open class LevelModule { ... }
```

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class TestLevelModule {
```

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class AppModule() { ... }
```

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class TestAppModule() { ... }
```

It works when I run the app, but when I run the test, `GameActivity` is not being injected. All field with `@Inject` are null.

Does anyone have any idea of what it's wrong?

---

If useful, the whole code and test are here:

- <s>https://github.com/lucasnlm/antimine-android/pull/95</s>
- <s>https://github.com/lucasnlm/antimine-android/pull/95/commits/fcc1b3782b8d456898529dd3ba2410ac5f2da6d5</s>

EDIT

I have no ideia why, but the tests passed on this PR:

- https://github.com/lucasnlm/antimine-android/pull/100

Comment: I cloned your repo, and the test runs, but fails, by changing Hilt's annotation processor from `kapt` to `annotationProcessor`

Comment: Using `kapt` the tests run too. But fails because they are not injected.

Comment: I have no ideia why, but the tests passed on CI.

Comment: This is a known bug when running Hilt Tests in Android Studio.  They have a work around to setup a Gradle Test configuration, and run the tests through gradle instead of the IDE.  Issue being tracked here: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1956

Answer (score 1):

according to the [testing guide](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#testing-features),

> you must replace the binding. Create a new module within the test
>   class that defines the test binding:

```
@UninstallModules(AnalyticsModule::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class SettingsActivityTest {

  @Module
  @InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
  abstract class TestModule {

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindAnalyticsService(
      analyticsServiceImpl: AnalyticsServiceImpl
    ): AnalyticsService
  }

  ...
}
```